# Search Documents Containing Certain Nested Objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, elasticsearch-5

My documents in Elasticsearch index have following format:

```
{
    timestamp: "123456789",
    tags: [
        { key:"tag1", "value": "val1" }, ...
    ]
}
```

I want get all documents which contain for example `{ key:"tag1" }` and `{ key:"tag2", "value": "val2" }` in their `tags` field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a bool query, where you specify how many nested query you need in the must section:

```
GET test_nested/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"nested" : {
            "path" : "tags",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"tags.key" : "tag1"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }},
        {"nested" : {
            "path" : "tags",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"tags.key" : "tag2"} },
                    { "match" : {"tags.value" : "val2"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case i have one nested query for selecting all documents with key "tag1" and the second nested query to select all documents with the "tag2"  and "value2".